# Spring Cloud Dataflow canceling task

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am curious is there any way to cancel launched task via REST API? 
Looking at `TaskOperations` class (spring-cloud-dataflow-rest-client:1.3.0) I don't see suitable method (ex: cancel, stop).

Am I supposed to always wait until task is finished?

Actually I am goint to use batch jobs and I guess it could be possible to get job execution id and stop it via `JobExecutionController`, but:

- there is no corresponding method in `Taskoperations` (not convenient)
- Is it really the only way to cancel task?

Comment: What platform?  My expectation is that this is a platform limitation (in that not all platforms would support a cancel option).

Comment: Target platform is YARN